# Are there cardinalities beyond Aleph 2?

Tags: set-theory

I'm familiar with Aleph Null, Aleph 1, and Aleph 2 but are there greater [uncountable] infinities beyond (examples) Natural numbers, Real numbers, and the number of curves that can pass through a point? If so, what are some tangible examples of these cardinalities: Aleph 3, 4, ...

Comment: In fact, *maybe* the cardinality of real numbers is already more than $\aleph_2$. But *maybe* it is just $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Ugh. I am starting to really hate that frigging book.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Just relax. Count to three...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Which book do you mean?

Comment: @Cornman: The one by Gamow.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Someone must have pointed out the problem as soon as the book appeared. Surprised they didn't come out with a corrected edition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next one after $\aleph_2$ is $\aleph_3$. There's also $c$, the cardinality of the reals. In fact $c=\aleph_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, but nobody knows which one...

Regading your new request for "tangible examples": In fact $\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of the integers, which I gather is what you mean by a tangible example. But no, $\aleph_1$ is not the carinality of the reals.

So what *are* these aleph things? One *can* prove that given a cardinal there is a smallest larger cardinal. So $\aleph_1$ is by definition the smmallest uncountale cardinal, $\aleph_2$ is by definition the smallest cardinal larger than $\aleph_1$, etc. That's as "tangible" as it gets.

Finally, regarding "Natural numbers, Real numbers, and the number of curves that can pass through a point?": Although you didn't actually say so, this sounds like you think the cardinality of that set of curves is larger then the reals. This is not so. If a "curve" is the graph of a continuous function, then the cardinality of the set of *all* curves, passing through a given point or not, is just $c$.

Comment: I thought c and ℵ1 were the same because it is the cardinality of reals. I don't think the continuum hypothesis requires the axiom of choice either.

Comment: @poetasis No. That statement is known as [the continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), and is known to not be decidable from [the usual axioms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). Indeed, in a precise sense ZFC can't prove anything about the exact value of the continuum in terms of the $\aleph$-hierarchy except that it [can't have countable cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)#K%C3%B6nig's_theorem_and_cofinality).

Comment: @poetasis No. I've heard that there are well-known popular books that state that $c=\aleph_1$, but it's not so. At least not provably so; it's been proved that you can't prove $c=\aleph_1$ and you also can't prove $c\ne\aleph_1$.

Comment: @poetasis "don't think CH requires AC" sounds like you're saying AC is not needed to prove CH. In fact you can't prove CH with or without AC.

Comment: It is _slightly_ more tangible to say that $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of isomorphism classes of total orders on $\mathbb N$ that are well-orders. (But still nothing that really engages the imagination).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes. Curiously, it seems to me that what's "tangible" depends on who you are. Many people find $c$ perfectly "tangible", being the cardinality of the reals. But (or so it seems to me) things like $\aleph_n$ are perfectly "tangible" to a set theorist, while $c$ is the "intangible" one...

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Just keep taking power sets of power sets ad infinitum.  There is no largest cardinal.

Answer (score 1):

To conceptualize larger cardinals, you can use power sets, for sure. If you want something larger than the cardinality of curves passing through a point, consider subsets of the set curves passing through a point.

$$|\mathcal{P}(A)|>|A|$$

Another way of looking at this approach is to consider the set of functions from a set of one cardinality to, for example, the set $\{0,1\}$. This set is equivalent to the power set of your original set, and its cardinality is greater. In symbols: $$|\left\{f|f:A\to\{0,1\}\right\}|>|A|$$